# Not able to create temp file in the desired directory

Tags: c++, macos, file-permissions

I need to create a temp file in a specified folder on MAC. However I am able to create the folder at the correct location but not able to create the file inside. I get an error saying it does not have permissions to create the file although i have passed 777 as file permission while creating the folder. please find my code below. I would like to mention that this problem is only on MAC. On windows it executes as expected. please let me know what the issue is.

```
    wxString curDir = SeeWorkingDir() + wxT("Temp\\"); //Gets the working directory

    if(!wxFileName::DirExists(curDir)) //Checks if directory exists
    wxFileName::Mkdir( curDir, 0777, wxPATH_MKDIR_FULL ); // creates the directory

    wxString jobcopy = wxFileName::CreateTempFileName(curDir); // should create temp file
```

Comment: curDir after first statement will be /users/...../../Temp/ where the file has to be created and also in case of MAC it will be SeeWorkingDir() + wxT("Temp/")

Comment: Did you actually create the folder or was it already created? Have you checked the actual permissions of the folder?

Comment: @PauliL I have created the directory myself.. and while creating i have passed the parameter 777 (for full permission).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have absolutely no idea what your "`SeeWorkingDir()`" function is returning, but if it's returning the application directory then you shouldn't be writing anything into there.

Why not replace "`SeeWorkingDir()`" with a path to somewhere on the Macintosh that *truly* is writable, like the "`/tmp/`" directory?

Comment: Thanks Michael. See working directory will return the temp area of MAC.. That is something like "users/darzen/library/cache/project/ and then I create a directory called Temp within that

Comment: "`/Users/michael/Library/Cache/`" doesn't exist on ***my*** machine. What makes you think it's going to exist on your user's machine?  If you are writing temp files, write them where they are expected to be written.  "`/tmp`" is a convenient place for C / C++ code like what you're writing.  Somewhere in "~/Library/Caches" is the right place for Objective C / native code.

Comment: users/Darzen/Library/Caches/project/   I am sorry I missed the 's' in caches

Comment: @Michael: The problem is not that it is not working in your machine but that it is not working in Darzens machine. And what makes you think SeeWorkingDir would return a fixed pathname?

Comment: @PauliL - because Darzen is trying to get C++ to work, I was suggesting to him to write into the "/tmp" folder instead of fighting with some non-fixed path where one of the components might be a non-writable or non-existent directory (which would lead to the problems he's hitting now).

Comment: @Michael: But we already know that the directory is writable since creating sub-directory did work. Further, there is no guarantee that /temp directory would exist. I think the correct way would be to use wxFileName::GetTempDir.

Comment: Well okay then @PauliL, you should suggest "wxFileName::GetTempDir" as an official answer.  B.T.W., "`/tmp`" *always* exists on a Macintosh file system.

Answer (score 0):

You have not explained what your function SeeWorkingDir() does.

Maybe you should use `wxFileName::GetTempDir` to specify the directory where you store the file. This should be platform independent.

Or, in your call wxFileName::CreateTempFileName(curDir), you could specify the `fileTemp` parameter to open the file directly.

See the documentation:
[wxWidgets 2.8.12 - wxFileName](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxfilename.html)